# dojo.store.Observable, JSON REST and queryEngine

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, datastore, restful-architecture

Does anybody know how to use the JsonRest store in dojo witn an Observable weapper, like the one in dojo.store.Observable?

What do I need, server side, to implement the store and make it work as an Observable one?  What about the client side? 
The documentation says http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/Observable.html

> If you are using a server side store like the JsonRest store, you will need to provide a queryEngine in order for the update objects to be properly included or excluded from queries. If a queryEngine is not available, observe listener will be called with an undefined index.

But, I have no idea what they mean. I have never created a store myself, and am not 100% familiar with queryEngine (to be honest, I find it a little confusing). Why is queryEngine needed? What does the doc mean by "undefined index"? And how do you write a queryEngine for a JsonRest store? Shouldn't I use some kind of web socket for an observable REST store, since other users might change the data as well?

Confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this quesiton is a bit old, but here's some info for future reference. Since this is a multi-part question, I'll break it down into separate pieces:

### 1) Server-side Implementation of JsonRest

There's a pretty decent write up on implementing the [server side of JsonRest Store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#method-and-restful-mapping). It shows exactly what headers JsonRest will generate and what content will be included in the rest. It helps form a mental model of how the JsonRest api is converted into HTTP.

### 2) Query Engine

Earlier in the same page, [how query() works client side](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#id4) is explained. Basically, the `query()` function needs to be able to receive an object literal (ex: `{title:'Learning Dojo',categoryid:5}`) and return the objects *in the store* that match those conditions. *"In the store"* meaning already loaded into memory on the client, not on the server.

Depending on what you're trying to do, there's probably no need to write your own queryEngine anyway -- just use the [built-in SimpleQueryEngine](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine.html#dojo-store-util-simplequeryengine) if you're building your own custom store. The engine just needs to be handed an object literal and it adds the whole dojo query() api for you.

### 3) Observables

My understanding is that the Observables monitor client side changes in the collection of objects (ex: adding or removing a result) or even within a specific object (ex: post 5 has changed title). It does NOT monitor changes that happen server-side. It simply provides a mechanism to notify other aspects of the client-side app that data changed so that all aspects of the page stay synchronized.

There's a whole write up on [using Observables](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/data_modeling/) under the headings 'Collection Data Binding' and 'Object Data Binding: dojo/Stateful'.

### 4) Concurrency

There's two things you'd want to do in order to keep your client side data synchronized with the server side data: a) polling for changes from other users on the server, b) using transactions to send data to the server.

a) To poll for changes to the data, you'd want to have your object store track the active query in a variable. Then, use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to run the query in the background again every so often. Make sure that widgets or other aspects of your application use Observables to monitor changes in the query result set(s) they depend on. That way, changes on the server by other users would automatically be reflected throughout your application.

b) Use transactions to combine actions that must be combined. Then, make sure the server sends back HTTP 200 Status codes (meaning 'It Worked!'). If the transactions returns a HTTP status in the 400s, then it didn't work for some reason, and you need to requery the data because something changed on the backend. For example, the record you want to update was deleted, so you can't update it. There's a [write up on transactions](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/data_modeling/) as well under the heading 'Transactional'

Comment: I accepted this answer for complete-ness. However, if you want to observe JsonRest stores, you will need to write your own Observable library. That's what I did with this: [JsonObservable.js]( https://github.com/mercmobily/hotplate/blob/master/node_modules/hotDojoStores/client/JsonObservable.js) Please note that I am in touch with the Dojo maintainer in order to render JsonObservable somehow obsolete (which is what I hope will happen)